# Sine ploting in python

Tags: python, plot

How I should plot the figure which has sine on the top of rectangular? 
I draw a rectangular with code:

```
def rectdraw(length_sec=1000):
    rect = []
    for time in range(0, 3000, 1):
        if time > 1000 and time < 2000:
            rect.append(1.2)
        else:
            rect.append(0)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(rect)
    plt.show()
```

But instead of value 1.2  I should get a sine wave. How I should modify my code?

[image: rectangular image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sine function is the following:

[image]

So, you need to define the amplitude, frequency and phase when using the sine function. So, I changed your function a bit where it takes another three arguments:

- The amplitude `a` (1 is the default value)
- The frequency `freq` (0.005 is the default value).
- The phase `ph` (0 as the default value)

```
def rectdraw(a=1, freq=0.005, ph=0, length_sec=1000):
    rect = []
    for time in range(0, 3000, 1):
        if time > 1000 and time < 2000:
            rect.append(1.2+(a*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*time + ph)))
        else:
            rect.append(0)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(rect)
    plt.show()
```

Running the previous function produced the following graph:
[image]

Comment: Glad I could help!